# RSA key not working with trustpoint used for IPSec

Tags: cisco, ipsec, ike

I'am trying to setup an IPsec IKEv2 tunnel where the local authentication mechanism is based on RSA. Therefore I have setup a trustpoint and I got a signed certificate for this setup.
Importing is successfull, nevertheless, when a StrongSwan Android client tries to open a connection, the IOS complains that it cannot get the private rsa key and the connection fails.

Any clue on what would be wrongly implemented?

Some useful output:
Commands used to create the trustpoint:

```
crypto key generate rsa exportable label ipsec modulus 2048
crypto ca trustpoint tp_ipsec_2017
 enrollment terminal pem
 crl optional
 fqdn rtr.example.net
 rsakeypair ipsec 
 subject-name C=BE,ST=city,L=area,O=Private,OU=Familly,CN=rtr.example.net

crypto ca enroll tp_ipsec_2017
! save the csr and submit to CA
crypto ca authenticate tp_ipsec_2017
! paste the ca bundle crt 
crypto ca import tp_ipsec_2017 certificate 
! paste the site crt
```

sh crypto pki trustpoint status:

```
rtr01#sh crypto pki trustpoints status
Trustpoint tp_ipsec_2017:
  Issuing CA certificate configured:
    Subject Name:
     cn=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,o=COMODO CA Limited,l=Salford,st=Greater Manchester,c=GB
    Fingerprint MD5: 83E10465 B722EF33 FF0B6F53 5E8D996B
    Fingerprint SHA1: 339CDD57 CFD5B141 169B615F F3142878 2D1DA639
  Router General Purpose certificate configured:
    Subject Name:
     cn=rtr.example.net,ou=PositiveSSL,ou=Domain Control Validated
    Fingerprint MD5: 6212CDAA 4DA68FF0 AE96F78A 315CC4F7
    Fingerprint SHA1: A038723A 42EEB9D1 735F65FE 8F7C369B F6DFDD81
  State:
    Keys generated ............. Yes (General Purpose, exportable)
    Issuing CA authenticated ....... Yes
    Certificate request(s) ..... Yes
```

sh logs:

```
000399: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:Received Packet [From 94.109.21.28:3148/To 67.209.124.251:500/VRF i0:f0]
Initiator SPI : 5369918ED0805852 - Responder SPI : 0000000000000000 Message id: 0
IKEv2 IKE_SA_INIT Exchange REQUEST
Payload contents:
 SA KE N NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP) NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP) NOTIFY(Unknown - 16430) NOTIFY(Unknown - 16431) NOTIFY(REDIRECT_SUPPORTED)

000400: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Verify SA init message
000401: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Insert SA
000402: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:Searching Policy with fvrf 0, local address 67.209.124.251
000403: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:Found Policy 'ikev2-policy'
000404: Jul 19 20:20:21.846: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Processing IKE_SA_INIT message
000405: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Retrieve configured trustpoint(s)
000406: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Retrieved trustpoint(s): 'tp_ipsec_2017'
000407: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Get Public Key Hashes of trustpoints
000408: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Getting of Public Key Hashes of trustpoints PASSED
000409: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Start PKI Session
000410: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Starting of PKI Session PASSED
000411: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Computing DH public key, DH Group 19
000412: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[Crypto Engine -> IKEv2] DH key Computation PASSED
000413: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Request queued for computation of DH key
000414: Jul 19 20:20:21.850: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Computing DH secret key, DH Group 19
000415: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[Crypto Engine -> IKEv2] DH key Computation PASSED
000416: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Request queued for computation of DH secret
000417: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Calculate SKEYSEED and create rekeyed IKEv2 SA
000418: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[Crypto Engine -> IKEv2] SKEYSEED calculation and creation of rekeyed IKEv2 SA PASSED
000419: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:IKEv2 responder - no config data to send in IKE_SA_INIT exch
000420: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Generating IKE_SA_INIT message
000421: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):IKE Proposal: 1, SPI size: 0 (initial negotiation),
Num. transforms: 4
   AES-CBC   SHA256   SHA256   DH_GROUP_256_ECP/Group 19
000422: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Retrieve configured trustpoint(s)
000423: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Retrieved trustpoint(s): 'tp_ipsec_2017'
000424: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Get Public Key Hashes of trustpoints
000425: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Getting of Public Key Hashes of trustpoints PASSED

000426: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Sending Packet [To 94.109.21.28:3148/From 67.209.124.251:500/VRF i0:f0]
Initiator SPI : 5369918ED0805852 - Responder SPI : 33466755FF746037 Message id: 0
IKEv2 IKE_SA_INIT Exchange RESPONSE
Payload contents:
 SA KE N VID VID NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP) NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP) CERTREQ NOTIFY(HTTP_CERT_LOOKUP_SUPPORTED)

000427: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Completed SA init exchange
000428: Jul 19 20:20:21.862: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Starting timer (30 sec) to wait for auth message

000429: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Received Packet [From 94.109.21.28:3863/To 67.209.124.251:500/VRF i0:f0]
Initiator SPI : 5369918ED0805852 - Responder SPI : 33466755FF746037 Message id: 1
IKEv2 IKE_AUTH Exchange REQUEST
Payload contents:
 IDi NOTIFY(INITIAL_CONTACT) CFG NOTIFY(ESP_TFC_NO_SUPPORT) SA TSi TSr NOTIFY(Unknown - 16396) NOTIFY(Unknown - 16399) NOTIFY(Unknown - 16417) NOTIFY(Unknown - 16420)

000430: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Stopping timer to wait for auth message
000431: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Checking NAT discovery
000432: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):NAT OUTSIDE found
000433: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):NAT detected float to init port 3863, resp port 4500
000434: Jul 19 20:20:21.910: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Searching policy based on peer's identity 'barbara' of type 'FQDN'
000435: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:found matching IKEv2 profile 'ikev2-profile'
000436: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:Searching Policy with fvrf 0, local address 67.209.124.251
000437: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:Found Policy 'ikev2-policy'
000438: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Verify peer's policy
000439: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Peer's policy verified
000440: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Check for EAP exchange
000441: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Generate my authentication data
000442: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:[IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Generate IKEv2 authentication data
000443: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:[Crypto Engine -> IKEv2] IKEv2 authentication data generation PASSED
000444: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Get my authentication method
000445: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):My authentication method is 'RSA'
000446: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Sign authentication data
000447: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Getting private key
000448: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Getting of private key FAILED
000449: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):: Failed to generate auth data: Failed to sign data
000450: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Verification of peer's authentication data FAILED
000451: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Sending authentication failure notify
000452: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Building packet for encryption.
Payload contents:
 NOTIFY(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)

000453: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Sending Packet [To 94.109.21.28:3863/From 67.209.124.251:4500/VRF i0:f0]
Initiator SPI : 5369918ED0805852 - Responder SPI : 33466755FF746037 Message id: 1
IKEv2 IKE_AUTH Exchange RESPONSE
Payload contents:
 ENCR

000454: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Auth exchange failed
000455: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):: Auth exchange failed
000456: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Abort exchange
000457: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SESSION ID = 8,SA ID = 1):Deleting SA
000458: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[IKEv2 -> PKI] Close PKI Session
000459: Jul 19 20:20:21.914: IKEv2:(SA ID = 1):[PKI -> IKEv2] Closing of PKI Session PASSED
000460: Jul 19 20:30:36 CET: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by admin on vty0 (IPV6)
```

sh run:

```
Current configuration : 21755 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 20:30:36 CET Thu Jul 19 2018 by admin
! NVRAM config last updated at 20:30:43 CET Thu Jul 19 2018 by admin
! NVRAM config last updated at 20:30:43 CET Thu Jul 19 2018 by admin
version 15.3
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime
service timestamps log datetime localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
service sequence-numbers
!
hostname rtr01
!
boot-start-marker
boot system flash c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.153-3.M10.bin
boot-end-marker
!
aqm-register-fnf
!
logging buffered 16386
logging rate-limit 100 except warnings
no logging console
no logging monitor
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa group server radius nas
 server name nas
!
aaa authentication enable default none
aaa authorization exec default none
aaa authorization commands 0 default none
aaa authorization commands 15 default none
aaa authorization network default if-authenticated
aaa authorization network ikev2_author_local if-authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
memory-size iomem 10
clock timezone CET 1 0
!
crypto pki trustpoint tp_ipsec_2017
 enrollment terminal pem
 fqdn rtr.example.net
 subject-name C=BE,ST=City,L=Area,O=Private,OU=Familly,CN=rtr.example.net
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair ipsec
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain tp_ipsec_2017
 certificate 4C0299EF6970C3E2E975E30FE1430091
  REMOVED_CERT
        quit
 certificate ca 2B2E6EEAD975366C148A6EDBA37C8C07
  COMMODO_BUNDLE_CA
        quit
no ip source-route
!
!
!
!


!
ip dhcp bootp ignore
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.11.0/24
 relay source 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0
 relay destination 192.168.10.5
!
ip dhcp pool 192.168.12.0/24
 relay source 192.168.12.0 255.255.255.0
 relay destination 192.168.10.5
!
!
!
no ip bootp server
ip domain name example.net
ip name-server 192.168.10.5
ip multicast-routing
ip cef
ip wccp check services all
ip wccp source-interface Vlan10
ip wccp web-cache redirect-list acl4_out_wccp group-list acl4_wccp_servers
ip wccp 70 redirect-list acl4_out_wccp group-list acl4_wccp_servers
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
ipv6 wccp check services all
ipv6 wccp source-interface Vlan10
ipv6 wccp web-cache redirect-list acl6_out_wccp group-list acl4_wccp_servers
ipv6 wccp 70 redirect-list acl6_out_wccp group-list acl4_wccp_servers
!
!
!
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid C897VA-K9 sn REMOVED
!
!
object-group network grp_passthrough_from
 host 192.168.11.10
 host 192.168.11.9
!
object-group network grp_passthrough_to
 host 8.8.8.8
 host 8.8.4.4
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 REMOVED
!
crypto ikev2 authorization policy ikev2-auth-policy
 pool pool4-ipsec
 dns 192.168.10.5
 def-domain example.net
 route set remote ipv4 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
!
crypto ikev2 proposal ikev2-proposal
 encryption aes-cbc-128 aes-cbc-256
 integrity sha256
 group 2 15 16 19 20 21
!
crypto ikev2 policy ikev2-policy
 proposal ikev2-proposal
!
!
crypto ikev2 profile ikev2-profile
 match identity remote any
 identity local fqdn rtr.example.net
 authentication remote eap query-identity
 authentication local rsa-sig
 pki trustpoint tp_ipsec_2017
 aaa authentication eap radius
 aaa authorization group eap list ikev2_author_local ikev2-auth-policy
 aaa authorization user eap cached
 virtual-template 1
!
!
!
controller VDSL 0
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ipsec-transform esp-aes 256 esp-sha256-hmac
 mode tunnel
!
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsec-profile
 set transform-set ipsec-transform
 set ikev2-profile ikev2-profile
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback20
 description Internal Users IPSec
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip wccp web-cache redirect in
 ip wccp 70 redirect in
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ipv6 address IPV6_PREFIX:403::1/64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 wccp web-cache redirect in
 ipv6 wccp 70 redirect in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_in_users in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_out_users out
!
interface ATM0
 no ip address
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
!
interface BRI0
 no ip address
 encapsulation hdlc
 shutdown
 isdn termination multidrop
!
interface Ethernet0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0.10
 description pppoe vdsl0 to bridge 1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 description Access Point
 switchport trunk native vlan 11
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,11,12,1002-1005
 switchport mode trunk
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 description NAS
 switchport access vlan 10
 no ip address
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 switchport access vlan 11
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 switchport access vlan 11
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet4
 description Xbox One
 switchport access vlan 11
 no ip address
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5
 description LG TV
 switchport access vlan 11
 no ip address
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet6
 switchport access vlan 11
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet7
 switchport access vlan 12
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet8
 description modem
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface Virtual-Template1 type tunnel
 ip unnumbered Loopback20
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsec-profile
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 description DMZ LAN
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group acl4_in_dmz in
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ipv6 address FE80::2000:1 link-local
 ipv6 address IPV6_PREFIX:400::1/64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_in_dmz in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_out_dmz out
!
interface Vlan11
 description Internal Users
 ip address 192.168.11.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip wccp web-cache redirect in
 ip wccp 70 redirect in
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ipv6 address IPV6_PREFIX:402::1/64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 wccp web-cache redirect in
 ipv6 wccp 70 redirect in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_in_users in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_out_users out
!
interface Vlan12
 description Guest Users
 ip address 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group acl4_in_guests in
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 rate-limit input 1024000 192000 384000 conform-action continue exceed-action drop
 rate-limit output 10024000 1879500 3759000 conform-action continue exceed-action drop
 ipv6 address IPV6_PREFIX:405::1/64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_in_guests in
 ipv6 traffic-filter acl6_out_guests out
!
interface Dialer1
 mtu 1492
 ip address negotiated
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 dialer-group 1
 ipv6 address FE80::10 link-local
 ipv6 address autoconfig default
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 dhcp client pd prefix_wan
 ppp authentication pap chap callin
 ppp chap hostname username@ISP
 ppp chap password 7 REMOVED
 ppp direction callout
 ppp pap sent-username username@ISP password 7 REMOVED
 ppp ipcp header-compression ack
 ppp ipcp dns request accept
 ppp ipcp address accept
 no cdp enable
!
ip local pool pool4-ipsec 192.168.20.10 192.168.20.100
no ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 25 interface Dialer1 25
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 80 interface Dialer1 80
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 465 interface Dialer1 465
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 587 interface Dialer1 587
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 873 interface Dialer1 873
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 993 interface Dialer1 993
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 5001 interface Dialer1 5001
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 5006 interface Dialer1 5006
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 6690 interface Dialer1 6690
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 6881 interface Dialer1 6881
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 8444 interface Dialer1 8444
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 16881 interface Dialer1 16881
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 38443 interface Dialer1 38443
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 41988 interface Dialer1 41988
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.10.5 6881 interface Dialer1 6881
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.10.5 443 interface Dialer1 443
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.11.9 3074 interface Dialer1 3074
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.11.9 88 interface Dialer1 88
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.11.9 3544 interface Dialer1 3544
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.11.9 3074 interface Dialer1 3074
ip nat inside source list acl4_nat_allowed interface Dialer1 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 192.168.10.192 255.255.255.192 192.168.10.5
ip ssh version 2
!
ip access-list extended acl4_in_dmz
 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.168.10.1
 permit tcp any any established
 permit udp 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 eq domain ntp 1812 bootps bootpc 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 deny   ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended acl4_in_guests
 permit ip any host 255.255.255.255
 permit ip any host 192.168.12.1
 permit udp any host 192.168.10.5 eq domain bootps bootpc
 deny   ip 192.168.12.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended acl4_nat_allowed
 permit icmp any any
 permit udp any any gt 1024
 permit tcp any any gt 1024
 permit ip any object-group grp_passthrough_to
 permit ip object-group grp_passthrough_from any
 deny   ip 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255 any log
 deny   ip 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
ip access-list extended acl4_out_wccp
 deny   ip any object-group grp_passthrough_to
 deny   ip object-group grp_passthrough_from any
 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
ip access-list extended acl4_ssh_allowed
 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
 deny   ip any any
ip access-list extended acl4_wccp_servers
 permit ip 192.168.10.192 0.0.0.63 any
!
ip radius source-interface Vlan10
ip access-list logging interval 10
kron occurrence backup at 0:30 1 recurring
 policy-list backup
!
kron policy-list backup
 cli copy running-config tftp://192.168.10.5/rtr01.txt
!
ipv6 route IPV6_PREFIX:400:FFFF:FFFF::/96 IPV6_PREFIX:400:211:32FF:FE92:491D
!
!
radius server nas
 address ipv4 192.168.10.5 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
 key 7 REMOVED
!
!
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_in_dmz
 permit icmp any any
 sequence 15 permit tcp any any established
 sequence 16 deny ipv6 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/64 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/56
 sequence 40 permit ipv6 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/64 any
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_in_guests
 sequence 100 deny ipv6 IPV6_PREFIX:405::/64 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/62
 permit ipv6 any any
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_in_users
 sequence 5 permit icmp any any
 sequence 10 permit tcp any any established
 permit ipv6 IPV6_PREFIX:402::/63 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/62
 sequence 25 permit tcp any any gt 1024
 sequence 26 permit udp any any gt 1024
 sequence 30 deny ipv6 any any
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_out_dmz
 permit icmp any any
 sequence 11 permit ipv6 IPV6_PREFIX:402::/63 IPV6_PREFIX:400::/64
 permit ipv6 any host IPV6_PREFIX:400:211:32FF:FE92:491D
 sequence 25 permit tcp any any established
 sequence 30 deny ipv6 any any
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_out_guests
 permit icmp any any
 deny ipv6 any any
 permit tcp any any established
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_out_users
 sequence 5 permit icmp any any
 sequence 10 permit tcp any any established
 sequence 60 deny ipv6 any any
!
ipv6 access-list acl6_ssh_allowed
 sequence 30 permit tcp IPV6_PREFIX:402::/63 any eq 22
 deny ipv6 any any
!
control-plane
!
!
!
mgcp behavior rsip-range tgcp-only
mgcp behavior comedia-role none
mgcp behavior comedia-check-media-src disable
mgcp behavior comedia-sdp-force disable
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
 vstack
alias exec sri show run interface
alias exec sid show int desc
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 30 0
 password 7 REMOVED
 logging synchronous
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 30
 access-class acl4_ssh_allowed in
 exec-timeout 30 0
 ipv6 access-class acl6_ssh_allowed in
 logging synchronous
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 30
 access-class acl4_ssh_allowed in
 exec-timeout 30 0
 ipv6 access-class acl6_ssh_allowed in
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
ntp source Dialer1
ntp master 3
ntp update-calendar
ntp server ip europe.pool.ntp.org
ntp server ipv6 be.pool.ntp.org prefer
```

sh crypto key mypubkey rsa

```
rtr01#sh crypto key mypubkey rsa
% Key pair was generated at: 20:06:49 CET Jul 19 2018
Key name: ipsec
Key type: RSA KEYS
 Storage Device: private-config
 Usage: General Purpose Key
 Key is exportable.
 Key Data:
  DATA
% Key pair was generated at: 20:06:49 CET Jul 19 2018
Key name: ipsec.server
Key type: RSA KEYS
Temporary key
 Usage: Encryption Key
 Key is not exportable.
 Key Data:
  KEY_DATA
rtr01#

rtr01#show crypto key storage
Default keypair storage device has not been set
Keys will be stored in NVRAM private config
```

sh crypto pki certificates:

```
rtr01#sh crypto pki certificates
Certificate
  Status: Available
  Certificate Serial Number (hex): 4C0299EF6970C3E2E975E30FE1430091
  Certificate Usage: General Purpose
  Issuer:
    cn=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    o=COMODO CA Limited
    l=Salford
    st=Greater Manchester
    c=GB
  Subject:
    Name: rtr.example.net
    cn=rtr.example.net
    ou=PositiveSSL
    ou=Domain Control Validated
  CRL Distribution Points:
    http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crl
  Validity Date:
    start date: 01:00:00 CET Jul 19 2018
    end   date: 00:59:59 CET Sep 29 2020
  Associated Trustpoints: tp_ipsec_2017
  Storage: nvram:COMODORSADom#91.cer

CA Certificate
  Status: Available
  Certificate Serial Number (hex): 2B2E6EEAD975366C148A6EDBA37C8C07
  Certificate Usage: Signature
  Issuer:
    cn=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    o=COMODO CA Limited
    l=Salford
    st=Greater Manchester
    c=GB
  Subject:
    cn=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    o=COMODO CA Limited
    l=Salford
    st=Greater Manchester
    c=GB
  CRL Distribution Points:
    http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSACertificationAuthority.crl
  Validity Date:
    start date: 01:00:00 CET Feb 12 2014
    end   date: 00:59:59 CET Feb 12 2029
  Associated Trustpoints: tp_ipsec_2017
  Storage: nvram:COMODORSACer#8C07CA.cer
```

sh ver

```
rtr01>sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, C800 Software (C800-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.3(3)M10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 28-Jul-17 15:47 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.2(3r)XC, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

rtr01 uptime is 4 days, 14 hours, 24 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 06:13:12 CET Mon Jul 16 2018
System image file is "flash:c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.153-3.M10.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload
Last reload reason: power-on

Cisco C897VA-K9 (revision 1.0) with 472064K/52224K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FGL204825EN
1 DSL controller
1 Ethernet interface
9 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
1 ISDN Basic Rate interface
1 ATM interface
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
DRAM configuration is 32 bits wide
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
250880K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash (Read/Write)



License Information for 'c800'
    License Level: advipservices   Type: Permanent
    Next reboot license Level: advipservices


Configuration register is 0x2102
```

sh log (crypto pki debug):

```
000481: Jul 21 10:18:51.630: CRYPTO_PKI: (A000E) Session started - identity not specified  
000482: Jul 21 10:18:51.706: CRYPTO_PKI: Rcvd request to end PKI session A000E.  
000483: Jul 21 10:18:51.706: CRYPTO_PKI: PKI session A000E has ended. Freeing all resources
```

sh crypto ikev2 diagnose error:

```
rtr01#sh crypto ikev2 diagnose error Exit Path Table - status: enable, current entry 2, deleted 0, max allow 50

Error(1): Expected keypair is unavailable

-Traceback= 689743Cz 60A1280z 604F908z 60BA3C4z 6043484z 6047660z 6047AF8z 60852E0z 6085368z 6054F80z 60A6888z 5CA00E8z 5C873BCz

Error(1): Detected NAT-d hash doesn't match

-Traceback= 689743Cz 60A1280z 604F908z 6063C1Cz 60661A8z 60437C8z 6047660z 6047AF8z 60852E0z 6085368z 6054F80z 60A6888z 5CA00E8z 5C873BCz
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router configuration. Just copy the configuration and paste it into the question. Use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). People do not want to click on unverified links, which will go bad over time, anyway.

Comment: The initial setup commands suggest you created a public/private keypair  called `ipsec`, and by virtue of `rsakeypair ipsec` under trustpoint config, the config is trying to use it.

What do the commands and subcommands of `show crypto key mypubkey rsa|all|... ` and `show crypto key storage`  let us know about that private key or keypair named `ipsec` ?  While you're at it, you might want to run `show crypto pki certificates` , too.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi thanks for the feedback, see above (added in the thread) the 2 show command (I just anonymized the RSA key content). The keypair is stored in the private config, do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: Well, to start with, I wanted to make sure that a key(pair) with label `ipsec` is available on the router.  If you tryt debugging PKI instead of IKEv2 with  `debug crypto pki...` and sub-debugs thereof,  can you get more information as to why retrieving the private key failed? (wrong file/label name? passphrase?)

Comment: and another comment - how old is that IOS on this box? I was pretty sure that the `crpyto ca ...` commands were replaced by `crypto pki ...` quite a few years back.  Did you actually use crypto _ca_ ...  to authenticate and enroll?

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi it's actually quite recent, was last patched less than 8 months ago (see sh ver I'v Added). The crypto pki or crypto ca behaves the same as far as I can tell (this is derived from some Cisco doc).

Comment: I did enable all crypto pki debugging (just not the perf ones) and Nothing outstanding, see above update to the question. Could the private-config storage location of the key be an issue here?

Comment: private-config should not be an issue;  that's where cerficates and keypairs go if you don't specifiy anything else.

Comment: On a sideline: When comparing your running-config to the IOS config section in  https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/flexvpn/116837-config-strongswan-ios-00.html#anc6, it seems that your aaa config is missing somethin the equivalent of  `aaa authentication login eap-list-radius group radius` from the example. The config defines the radius server group (called `radius`, but the ikev2 profile references the radius server group directly, instead of an item from the aaa methods.

Comment: Another suggestion from experience, which will help to tell things apart. 

1. Use UPPERCASE for items you name; like TP_IPSEC2017 instead of tp_ipsec2017, or TSET_IPSEC instead of ipsec-transform. They can be spotted a lot easier in a longish config file.

2. for these named items use a prefix like TSET_,  IPSECPROF_, IKEPROF_, PMAP_, CMAP_ ACL_ etc.  Yes, you will type more. Yes, it seems exaggerated.  But yes, your colleagues and team mates will  have less trouble finding the config items and understanding the config.

Comment: hmm,, advise taken for the naming convention. As for the rest; idd I was missing an aaa command although it does not solve the issue with this rsa private key.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I just added one last show command at the very bottom. Seems like IKE believes it should use some rsa key which it can't get, no idea why/which key. Any clue?

Comment: Nope, I'm at a loss here. This is now going into guesswork. I'd start by retrieving the private key from the router (presumed exportable) and keep it in a safe place, along with the certificate signed by the CA. Check with some openssl-style tool (Hint: XCA) if re-exported private key and certificate still are the correct ones - maybe you inadvertedly overwrote the original private key).  Based on these, you should be able to start from scratch by (re)importing  private key and signed public key (see `crypto key import rsa ...`).